# Conditional formatting rules over multiple rows

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

To start I have all the days of the month going across row 2 using up columns G through AI.

I also have in row 3 from columns G through AI the following function =IF(G$2=TODAY(),1,) This function changes according to the column: H$3, I$3, J$3 … etc to AI$3

Below this are series of tasks that are divided by date depending on what is being done that day so I will refer to this area as the ‘task area’.

What I’ve been using in the task area is the conditional formatting “Use a formula to determine which cells to format”.  When I reference the first column I use $G$3=1 and then apply the formatting to this column (in this case border the left and right side of all cells affected) and it works fine.  I’ve run into a problem in that I now have to set up a rule for every column from G3:AI3.  It is workable but not what I would like to ideally have set up, and it creates in some months 31 rules (this example 28 as I’m working in February) that are in existence to provide the formatting effect I want.

I’m wondering if there are any suggestions or directions to achieve the ideal which is one rule that can apply to the entire task area, but be able to work within the parameters, in this case the date of each individual column?

I have tried using the formula G3:AI3=1 but this comes back as an error as the rule for the conditional formatting.  I have toyed with using cell values but as it stands the task area already has conditional formatting applied and found this conflicted with this conditional formatting, and really didn’t look the way I was hoping anyway.  I hope this is clear, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It's a little unclear, but I think if for your formula (with all your day columns highlighted) you use `=G$3=1`, and apply that to the range `$G$3:$AI$3` (if you want it in row 3. Does that work?  Basically, when you use `=$G$3=1`, it's *always* looking at `G3` to be `1`.  If you're trying to apply it to individual columns, un-anchor the column reference.

Comment: if I could accept this answer I would because it was the answer I was seeking.  Thanks